# Data not getting pulled in right format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query two tables in oracle. ManagerStrategy and Fund table. One Manager Strategy will have one or more funds. I basically need to result set that would return data in the following format. The Fund table has managerstrategy_id foreign key

For e.g

```
 ManagerStategyId, ManagerStrategyName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStategyId, ManagerStrategyName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
```

The query that I have return below pull all the data in one row. How do I pull the data as per the format mentioned above. Is it Union

```
 Select m.id as ManagerStrategyId, m.name_text as ManagerStrategyName ,f.id as  FundId,f.name_text as FundName, f.managerstrategy_id 
from mgr.managerstrategy m 
   inner join mgr.fund f on m.id = f.managerstrategy_id
 where m.investment_status_id in (1,4,134)
 order by m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if you had supplied some sample data... I made up my own. Although this is not a coding service, I decided to take up the challenge anyway:

```
WITH
    managerstrategy AS
        (SELECT 1 AS id, 'Bogus Strategy' AS name_text FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Unrealistic Strategy' FROM DUAL),
    fund AS
        (SELECT 1 AS managerstrategy_id, 'Small return' AS name_text, 1 AS id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 as, 'Medium return', 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 as, 'Big return', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 as, 'Green Fund', 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 as, 'Red Fund', 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 as, 'Blue Fund', 6 FROM DUAL),
    merged AS
        (SELECT m.id            AS managerstrategyid
              , m.name_text     AS managerstrategyname
              , f.id            AS fundid
              , f.name_text     AS fundname
              , f.managerstrategy_id
              , 1               AS s
           FROM managerstrategy  m
                INNER JOIN fund f ON m.id = f.managerstrategy_id)
SELECT id, name_text, 1 AS s, TO_CHAR( id ) || ', ' || name_text AS csv FROM managerstrategy
UNION ALL
SELECT managerstrategyid
     , fundname
     , 2                                                    AS s
     , TO_CHAR( managerstrategyid ) || ', ' || fundname     AS csv
  FROM merged
ORDER BY 1
       , 3
       , 1
```

Just the CSV column from the result set:
CSV

```
1, Bogus Strategy
1, Medium return
1, Big return
1, Small return
2, Unrealistic Strategy
2, Red Fund
2, Blue Fund
2, Green Fund
```